# Will an EntityManager with context type TRANSACTION in a Singleton join an external bean-managed transaction?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, transactions, entitymanager

Suppose I have a `Singleton` bean with an `EntityManager` in it. The singleton also specifies (on method or class level) a transaction attribute `REQUIRED`. The entity manager is obtained via an `@PersistenceContext` injection which specifies persistence context type `TRANSACTION`. For all intents and purposes, if a method on this singleton is invoked with an existing transaction, the entity manager should join the transaction or possibly provide an already existing one linked to that transaction via proxy. If such a method is invoked outside of a transaction a new transaction will be started for the duration of the method invocation.

Now suppose we have a second bean which uses bean-managed transactions and injects the singleton. If it explicitly starts a user transaction and then invokes a method on the singleton, will the entity manager in that method join that user transaction? Will the jump from bean-managed to container-managed transaction context even work? I know the other way around doesn't and forms a barrier.

The singleton class:

```
@Singleton
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class PersistenceSingleton {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "test", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    private EntityManager em;

    public void doStuff() {

        // perform actions with the entity manager that imply changes in the database

    }

}
```

The bean with user transactions (might as well be stateless or stateful):

```
@Singleton
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class PersistenceFacade {

    @EJB
    private PeristenceSingleton ps;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction userTx;

    public void doStuff() {
        userTx.begin();
        ps.doStuff();
        userTx.commit();
    }

}
```

Does the transaction started in method `doStuff()` of the `PersistenceFacade` get taken into account when invoking `doStuff()` on the `PersistenceSingleton`? Does the entity manager automatically join the transaction and behave as expected from transaction isolation during concurrent access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserTransaction is used for changing the default transaction demarcation but we still control the JTA transactions.

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/types-of-entity-managers-application-managed-entitymanager.html says:

> If you have UserTransaction you can start demarcating what is to be executed within the transaction. Notice that you’re still controlling
>   the JTA transactions

so The persistence context propagation rule will be applied for UserTransaction demarcation.

pro JPA book says:

> When a method is invoked on the transaction-scoped entity manager, it
>   must first see whether there is a propagated persistence context. If
>   one exists, the entity manager uses this persistence context to carry
>   out the operation. All subsequent transaction-scoped entity manager
>   operations, in this component or any other, will thereafter use this
>   newly created persistence context. This behavior works independently
>   of whether container-managed or bean-managed transaction demarcation
>   has been used.

the answer to your questions is yes(first question)

> Does the entity manager automatically join the transaction and behave
>   as expected from transaction isolation during concurrent access?

entity manager checks the existence of a propagated persistence context and uses it.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I left this out in the example code but I actually specify bean-managed concurrency on the "facade" class (the one using the singleton with the entity manager) and will either do the same or use read locks on the singleton. Although the entity manager itself may not be thread-safe, since the invocations from different threads will have separate transactions it should be using separate persistence contexts anyway. I'll dig some more into whether that avoids any issues or not.